# Expectation value for Bogoliubov quasiparticle operators

Tags: homework-and-exercises, solid-state-physics, superconductivity, many-body

While calculating some expectation values for Bogoliubov quasiparticles in the context of the BCS theory of superconductivity, I stumbled across

$\langle\hat{\beta}_{\bf{k}\uparrow}^{\dagger}\hat{\beta}_{\bf{-k}\downarrow}^{\dagger}\rangle=0$,

where $\hat{\beta}_{\bf{k}\uparrow}^{\dagger}$ and $\hat{\beta}_{\bf{-k}\downarrow}^{\dagger}$ denote creation operators for these hybridized hole-electron quasiparticle states and are defined in terms of electron annihilation and creation operators according to

$\hat{\beta}_{\bf{k}\uparrow}^{\dagger}=u_{\bf{k}}\hat{c}_{\bf{k}\uparrow}^{\dagger}-v_{\bf{k}}\hat{c}_{\bf{-k}\downarrow}$,
$\hat{\beta}_{\bf{-k}\downarrow}^{\dagger}=v_{\bf{k}}\hat{c}_{\bf{k}\uparrow}+u_{\bf{k}}\hat{c}_{\bf{-k}\downarrow}^{\dagger}$.

Is anybody able to tell why the above expectation value should vanish? I know creating two Bogoliubov quasiparticles at the same time would violate energy conservation, but how can I show this equality by inserting the definitions of the operators and applying some commutator algebra on the electron annihilation/creation operators?

Comment: Are you sure about your definitions? $\hat{\beta}_{\bf{k}\uparrow}^{\dagger}=u_{\bf{k}}\hat{c}_{\bf{k}\uparrow}^{\dagger}-v_{\bf{k}}^{*}\hat{c}_{\bf{-k}\downarrow}$,
$\hat{\beta}_{\bf{-k}\downarrow}^{\dagger}=v_{\bf{k}}\hat{c}_{\bf{k}\uparrow}+u_{\bf{k}}\hat{c}_{\bf{-k}\downarrow}^{\dagger}$. Maybe in the second one one of the constants should be conjugated

Comment: If that is the case then try to expand, two expected values will have only creation/annihilation operators, those will be zero. you will then have two left. Next use the fact that $\langle \hat{c}_{k\uparrow}^\dagger {c}_{k\uparrow} \rangle$ = $f(E_{k\uparrow})$ (with $f(E)$ the Fermi-Dirac distribution). For the other one is $\langle \hat{c}_{k\downarrow} {c}_{k\downarrow}^\dagger \rangle$ = $f(-E_{k\downarrow})$. Then use the symmetry and probably they will cancel each other out.

Comment: Actually none of them should be complex conjugated, but I just wrote the question down in a hurry and did too much copy-pasting. Still, when I had tried to show that I was using the right coefficients. Thanks however

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your angular brackets denote expecatation in BCS bround state in which $\beta|gnd\rangle=0$ your result should be immediate--- no algebra required. The diagonalized Hamiltonian is a sum $\sum_i E_i \beta_i^\dagger\beta_i$ and commutes with the quasiparticle number. But  $\beta^\dagger_i\beta^\dagger_j|gnd\rangle$ is an energy eigenstate that differs by 2 in q-particle number, and is therefore orthogonal to $|gnd\rangle$.

Comment: That sounds really reasonable. Thanks a lot.